# Invalid length for a Base-64 char array

Tags: c#, authentication, encryption

I am working on Decrypt Password and i stuck on this error Invalid length for a Base-64 char array.I am trying too many things but all in vain my project is stuck due to this error .Here is my code.

```
public string PasswordDecrypt(string sQueryString)
    {

        byte[] buffer;
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider loCryptoClass = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider loCryptoProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();


        try
        {
            string base64String;
            char[] base64CharArray;
            base64CharArray = new char[sQueryString.Length];
            base64String = new string(base64CharArray);
            Convert.FromBase64String(sQueryString);
            buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(sQueryString);
            loCryptoClass.Key = loCryptoProvider.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sQueryString.Replace("","+")));
            loCryptoClass.IV = lbtVector;
            return ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(loCryptoClass.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            loCryptoClass.Clear();
            loCryptoProvider.Clear();
            loCryptoClass = null;
            loCryptoProvider = null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: On which line is the exception being thrown?

Comment: lbtVector is not declared.

Comment: lbtVector is declared still have the erro

Comment: Is it just me? It looks like the first 4/5 lines here (including the first FromBase64String) do nothing whatsoever...?

Comment: OK; what is the input here? What is the value of sQueryString? Is it actually base-64?

Comment: You also don't actually use the decoded byte[] - after the base-64 decode you ignore that value and then get the ASCII *encode* of the value... This code is deeply confused, with lots of operations that are then discarded. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: You then have a "decrypt" function that actually performs a *hash* (which is *not* decryption). A hash produces arbitrary byte[] - which you then run through an ASCII decode - but that decode makes no sense unless the input byte[] is known to be ASCII-encoded data, which a hash most certainly ***is not***. There are so many things wrong here that I think you really need to stop and tell us what you are trying to do: because I guarantee you - whatever you think this code does: it doesn't. We can't infer your intent from this code - it is too far gone.

Comment: the value of SQueryString in the password enter by the user

Comment: @Raheel it is very unlikely that their password is base-64. So simply: don't try to base-64-decode something that isn't actually base-64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passwords should never be decrypted (or encrypted, for that matter). You should be creating a hash of the password (preferably salted) when creating/updating your credential store and then comparing that hash to a hash derived from whatever the user enters when attempting to authenticate.

This is an implementation I've used in the past (which has some faults but works in non-critical apps):

```
public class HashProvider
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Computes the SHA1 hash from the given string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stringToHash">The string to hash.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetSHA1Hash(string stringToHash)
    {
        var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToHash);
        var hashData = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(data);

        return String.Concat(hashData.Select(b => b.ToString("X2")));
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Computes the SHA1 hash from the given string, and then encodes the hash as a Base64 string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stringToHash">The string to hash.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetSHA1toBase64Hash(string stringToHash)
    {
        var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToHash);
        var hashData = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(data);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(hashData);
    }
}
```

Comment: The importance of salting cannot be understated - rainbow tables etc. However, while I agree strongly with what you say - it doesn't address the base-64 question, which would presumably apply after hashing too.

Comment: How can i do this i m newbie on C# i have to design and develop login screen where user enter password which decrypted

Comment: Oddly enough, if you look at the code, the OP's "decrypt" is actually performing a hash. It is not clear whether this is intentional.

Comment: @Raheel if the user enters their password, why do you need to "decrypt" anything? *they just told you their password*. There are two things you could do with a password: *encrypt* it (which is usually bad, as noted in this answer), or *hash* it (preferably with salt)

Comment: @MarcGravell Yeah, it looks like the OP is trying to initialize the DES provider's key and initialization vector with a Base64 hash. I gave up trying to grok what he wanted and figured it was better to post a *slightly* better method for dealing with passwords.

Comment: @Raheel Input controls, whether WinForms or HTML, do not encrypt their values; w/o a SSL connection you can easily see the value in a password's POST value, for instance. So, what you really need to do is verify that the password entered will hash to the same value you've stored; a string, when hashed with the same algorithm (and the same salt, if used), will always generate the same hash - that's how the rainbow tables Marc mentions work (I'm grossly simplifying there).